# How to match one number in url with regex

Tags: regex

I have this URL and I only want to match 4 which can be any number from 0-99.

```
/img/4.png?t=1351606887
```

What's the regex to match the number 4 and any other number only?

Comment: Do you want to match the number 4 only if it appears before .png? Or is it okay if find the number 4 after t=?

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on how flexible your URL can be. Depending on your regex flavor you can either use lookarounds:

```
(?<=/img/)\d+(?=\.png)
```

Or a capturing group:

```
/img/(\d+)\.png
```

In the latter case you will match `/img/4.png` but the first captured group will contain only the `4`.

Which variant you can use, and how to retrieve the capture content really depends on your language/tool.

Comment: Damn it @m.buettner! Can't get a word in when you're online :D

Comment: @acheong87 sorry about that :D

Comment: is this javascript? javascript doesn't support lookbehinds (the `(?<=...)` thing). Use the second version instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
/\/[0-9]+/
```

Will that suffice, you think?